# Multiple Slider

Tags: slider, sliders

How can i make multiple slider in same page? Second slider not working i mean all sliders working in same page and they are different sliders. I think its name is multiple slider. I couldnt find information about that.

Sorry my English. Thank you for help.

```js
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(factory);
  } else {
    // Browser globals
    root.Dragdealer = factory();
  }
}(this, function () {

var Dragdealer = function(wrapper, options) {

  this.bindMethods();
  this.options = this.applyDefaults(options || {});
  this.wrapper = this.getWrapperElement(wrapper);
  if (!this.wrapper) {
    return;
  }
  this.handle = this.getHandleElement(this.wrapper, this.options.handleClass);
  if (!this.handle) {
    return;
  }
  this.init();
  this.bindEventListeners();
};
Dragdealer.prototype = {
  defaults: {
    disabled: false,
    horizontal: true,
    vertical: false,
    slide: true,
    steps: 0,
    snap: false,
    loose: false,
    speed: 0.1,
    xPrecision: 0,
    yPrecision: 0,
    handleClass: 'handle',
    css3: true,
    requestAnimationFrame: false,
    activeClass: 'active',
    tapping: true
  },
  init: function() {
    if (this.options.css3) {
      triggerWebkitHardwareAcceleration(this.handle);
    }
    this.value = {
      prev: [-1, -1],
      current: [this.options.x || 0, this.options.y || 0],
      target: [this.options.x || 0, this.options.y || 0]
    };
    this.offset = {
      wrapper: [0, 0],
      mouse: [0, 0],
      prev: [-999999, -999999],
      current: [0, 0],
      target: [0, 0]
    };
    this.change = [0, 0];
    this.stepRatios = this.calculateStepRatios();

    this.activity = false;
    this.dragging = false;
    this.tapping = false;

    this.reflow();
    if (this.options.disabled) {
      this.disable();
    }
  },
  applyDefaults: function(options) {
    for (var k in this.defaults) {
      if (!options.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        options[k] = this.defaults[k];
      }
    }
    return options;
  },
  getWrapperElement: function(wrapper) {
    if (typeof(wrapper) == 'string') {
      return document.getElementById(wrapper);
    } else {
      return wrapper;
    }
  },
  getHandleElement: function(wrapper, handleClass) {
    var childElements,
        handleClassMatcher,
        i;
    if (wrapper.getElementsByClassName) {
      childElements = wrapper.getElementsByClassName(handleClass);
      if (childElements.length > 0) {
        return childElements[0];
      }
    } else {
      handleClassMatcher = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + handleClass + '(\\s|$)');
      childElements = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('*');
      for (i = 0; i < childElements.length; i++) {
        if (handleClassMatcher.test(childElements[i].className)) {
          return childElements[i];
        }
      }
    }
  },
  calculateStepRatios: function() {
    var stepRatios = [];
    if (this.options.steps > 1) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.options.steps - 1; i++) {
        stepRatios[i] = i / (this.options.steps - 1);
      }
    }
    return stepRatios;
  },
  setWrapperOffset: function() {
    this.offset.wrapper = Position.get(this.wrapper);
  },
  calculateBounds: function() {
    var bounds = {
      top: this.options.top || 0,
      bottom: -(this.options.bottom || 0) + this.wrapper.offsetHeight,
      left: this.options.left || 0,
      right: -(this.options.right || 0) + this.wrapper.offsetWidth
    };
    bounds.availWidth = (bounds.right - bounds.left) - this.handle.offsetWidth;
    bounds.availHeight = (bounds.bottom - bounds.top) - this.handle.offsetHeight;
    return bounds;
  },
  calculateValuePrecision: function() {
    var xPrecision = this.options.xPrecision || Math.abs(this.bounds.availWidth),
        yPrecision = this.options.yPrecision || Math.abs(this.bounds.availHeight);
    return [
      xPrecision ? 1 / xPrecision : 0,
      yPrecision ? 1 / yPrecision : 0
    ];
  },
  bindMethods: function() {
    this.animateWithRequestAnimationFrame = bind(this.animateWithRequestAnimationFrame, this);
    this.animate = bind(this.animate, this);
    this.onHandleMouseDown = bind(this.onHandleMouseDown, this);
    this.onHandleTouchStart = bind(this.onHandleTouchStart, this);
    this.onDocumentMouseMove = bind(this.onDocumentMouseMove, this);
    this.onWrapperTouchMove = bind(this.onWrapperTouchMove, this);
    this.onWrapperMouseDown = bind(this.onWrapperMouseDown, this);
    this.onWrapperTouchStart = bind(this.onWrapperTouchStart, this);
    this.onDocumentMouseUp = bind(this.onDocumentMouseUp, this);
    this.onDocumentTouchEnd = bind(this.onDocumentTouchEnd, this);
    this.onHandleClick = bind(this.onHandleClick, this);
    this.onWindowResize = bind(this.onWindowResize, this);
  },
  bindEventListeners: function() {
    // Start dragging
    addEventListener(this.handle, 'mousedown', this.onHandleMouseDown);
    addEventListener(this.handle, 'touchstart', this.onHandleTouchStart);
    // While dragging
    addEventListener(document, 'mousemove', this.onDocumentMouseMove);
    addEventListener(this.wrapper, 'touchmove', this.onWrapperTouchMove);
    // Start tapping
    addEventListener(this.wrapper, 'mousedown', this.onWrapperMouseDown);
    addEventListener(this.wrapper, 'touchstart', this.onWrapperTouchStart);
    // Stop dragging/tapping
    addEventListener(document, 'mouseup', this.onDocumentMouseUp);
    addEventListener(document, 'touchend', this.onDocumentTouchEnd);

    addEventListener(this.handle, 'click', this.onHandleClick);
    addEventListener(window, 'resize', this.onWindowResize);

    this.animate(false, true);
    if (this.options.requestAnimationFrame) {
      this.interval = requestAnimationFrame(this.animateWithRequestAnimationFrame);
    } else {
      this.timeOffset = 25;
      this.interval = setInterval(this.animate, this.timeOffset);
    }
  },
  unbindEventListeners: function() {
    removeEventListener(this.handle, 'mousedown', this.onHandleMouseDown);
    removeEventListener(this.handle, 'touchstart', this.onHandleTouchStart);
    removeEventListener(document, 'mousemove', this.onDocumentMouseMove);
    removeEventListener(this.wrapper, 'touchmove', this.onWrapperTouchMove);
    removeEventListener(this.wrapper, 'mousedown', this.onWrapperMouseDown);
    removeEventListener(this.wrapper, 'touchstart', this.onWrapperTouchStart);
    removeEventListener(document, 'mouseup', this.onDocumentMouseUp);
    removeEventListener(document, 'touchend', this.onDocumentTouchEnd);
    removeEventListener(this.handle, 'click', this.onHandleClick);
    removeEventListener(window, 'resize', this.onWindowResize);
    if (this.options.requestAnimationFrame) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(this.interval);
    } else {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  },
  onHandleMouseDown: function(e) {
    Cursor.refresh(e);
    preventEventDefaults(e);
    stopEventPropagation(e);
    this.activity = false;
    this.startDrag();
  },
  onHandleTouchStart: function(e) {
    Cursor.refresh(e);
    stopEventPropagation(e);
    this.activity = false;
    this.startDrag();
  },
  onDocumentMouseMove: function(e) {
    Cursor.refresh(e);
    if (this.dragging) {
      this.activity = true;
    }
  },
  onWrapperTouchMove: function(e) {
    Cursor.refresh(e);
    if (!this.activity && this.draggingOnDisabledAxis()) {
      if (this.dragging) {
        this.stopDrag();
      }
      return;
    }
    preventEventDefaults(e);
    this.activity = true;
  },
  onWrapperMouseDown: function(e) {
    Cursor.refresh(e);
    preventEventDefaults(e);
    this.startTap();
  },
  onWrapperTouchStart: function(e) {
    Cursor.refresh(e);
    preventEventDefaults(e);
    this.startTap();
  },
  onDocumentMouseUp: function(e) {
    this.stopDrag();
    this.stopTap();
  },
  onDocumentTouchEnd: function(e) {
    this.stopDrag();
    this.stopTap();
  },
  onHandleClick: function(e) {
    if (this.activity) {
      preventEventDefaults(e);
      stopEventPropagation(e);
    }
  },
  onWindowResize: function(e) {
    this.reflow();
  },
  enable: function() {
    this.disabled = false;
    this.handle.className = this.handle.className.replace(/\s?disabled/g, '');
  },
  disable: function() {
    this.disabled = true;
    this.handle.className += ' disabled';
  },
  reflow: function() {
    this.setWrapperOffset();
    this.bounds = this.calculateBounds();
    this.valuePrecision = this.calculateValuePrecision();
    this.updateOffsetFromValue();
  },
  getStep: function() {
    return [
      this.getStepNumber(this.value.target[0]),
      this.getStepNumber(this.value.target[1])
    ];
  },
  getValue: function() {
    return this.value.target;
  },
  setStep: function(x, y, snap) {
    this.setValue(
      this.options.steps && x > 1 ? (x - 1) / (this.options.steps - 1) : 0,
      this.options.steps && y > 1 ? (y - 1) / (this.options.steps - 1) : 0,
      snap
    );
  },
  setValue: function(x, y, snap) {
    this.setTargetValue([x, y || 0]);
    if (snap) {
      this.groupCopy(this.value.current, this.value.target);
      this.updateOffsetFromValue();
      this.callAnimationCallback();
    }
  },
  startTap: function() {
    if (this.disabled || !this.options.tapping) {
      return;
    }

    this.tapping = true;
    this.setWrapperOffset();

    this.setTargetValueByOffset([
      Cursor.x - this.offset.wrapper[0] - (this.handle.offsetWidth / 2),
      Cursor.y - this.offset.wrapper[1] - (this.handle.offsetHeight / 2)
    ]);
  },
  stopTap: function() {
    if (this.disabled || !this.tapping) {
      return;
    }
    this.tapping = false;

    this.setTargetValue(this.value.current);
  },
  startDrag: function() {
    if (this.disabled) {
      return;
    }
    this.dragging = true;
    this.setWrapperOffset();

    this.offset.mouse = [
      Cursor.x - Position.get(this.handle)[0],
      Cursor.y - Position.get(this.handle)[1]
    ];
    if (!this.wrapper.className.match(this.options.activeClass)) {
      this.wrapper.className += ' ' + this.options.activeClass;
    }
  },
  stopDrag: function() {
    if (this.disabled || !this.dragging) {
      return;
    }
    this.dragging = false;

    var target = this.groupClone(this.value.current);
    if (this.options.slide) {
      var ratioChange = this.change;
      target[0] += ratioChange[0] * 4;
      target[1] += ratioChange[1] * 4;
    }
    this.setTargetValue(target);
    this.wrapper.className = this.wrapper.className.replace(' ' + this.options.activeClass, '');
  },
  callAnimationCallback: function() {
    var value = this.value.current;
    if (this.options.snap && this.options.steps > 1) {
      value = this.getClosestSteps(value);
    }
    if (!this.groupCompare(value, this.value.prev)) {
      if (typeof(this.options.animationCallback) == 'function') {
        this.options.animationCallback.call(this, value[0], value[1]);
      }
      this.groupCopy(this.value.prev, value);
    }
  },
  callTargetCallback: function() {
    if (typeof(this.options.callback) == 'function') {
      this.options.callback.call(this, this.value.target[0], this.value.target[1]);
    }
  },
  animateWithRequestAnimationFrame: function (time) {
    if (time) {
      // using requestAnimationFrame
      this.timeOffset = this.timeStamp ? time - this.timeStamp : 0;
      this.timeStamp = time;
    } else {
      // using setTimeout(callback, 25) polyfill
      this.timeOffset = 25;
    }
    this.animate();
    this.interval = requestAnimationFrame(this.animateWithRequestAnimationFrame);
  },
  animate: function(direct, first) {
    if (direct && !this.dragging) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.dragging) {
      var prevTarget = this.groupClone(this.value.target);

      var offset = [
        Cursor.x - this.offset.wrapper[0] - this.offset.mouse[0],
        Cursor.y - this.offset.wrapper[1] - this.offset.mouse[1]
      ];
      this.setTargetValueByOffset(offset, this.options.loose);

      this.change = [
        this.value.target[0] - prevTarget[0],
        this.value.target[1] - prevTarget[1]
      ];
    }
    if (this.dragging || first) {
      this.groupCopy(this.value.current, this.value.target);
    }
    if (this.dragging || this.glide() || first) {
      this.updateOffsetFromValue();
      this.callAnimationCallback();
    }
  },
  glide: function() {
    var diff = [
      this.value.target[0] - this.value.current[0],
      this.value.target[1] - this.value.current[1]
    ];
    if (!diff[0] && !diff[1]) {
      return false;
    }
    if (Math.abs(diff[0]) > this.valuePrecision[0] ||
        Math.abs(diff[1]) > this.valuePrecision[1]) {
      this.value.current[0] += diff[0] * this.options.speed * this.timeOffset / 25;
      this.value.current[1] += diff[1] * this.options.speed * this.timeOffset / 25;
    } else {
      this.groupCopy(this.value.current, this.value.target);
    }
    return true;
  },
  updateOffsetFromValue: function() {
    if (!this.options.snap) {
      this.offset.current = this.getOffsetsByRatios(this.value.current);
    } else {
      this.offset.current = this.getOffsetsByRatios(
        this.getClosestSteps(this.value.current)
      );
    }
    if (!this.groupCompare(this.offset.current, this.offset.prev)) {
      this.renderHandlePosition();
      this.groupCopy(this.offset.prev, this.offset.current);
    }
  },
  renderHandlePosition: function() {

    var transform = '';
    if (this.options.css3 && StylePrefix.transform) {
      if (this.options.horizontal) {
        transform += 'translateX(' + this.offset.current[0] + 'px)';
      }
      if (this.options.vertical) {
        transform += ' translateY(' + this.offset.current[1] + 'px)';
      }
      this.handle.style[StylePrefix.transform] = transform;
      return;
    }

    if (this.options.horizontal) {
      this.handle.style.left = this.offset.current[0] + 'px';
    }
    if (this.options.vertical) {
      this.handle.style.top = this.offset.current[1] + 'px';
    }
  },
  setTargetValue: function(value, loose) {
    var target = loose ? this.getLooseValue(value) : this.getProperValue(value);

    this.groupCopy(this.value.target, target);
    this.offset.target = this.getOffsetsByRatios(target);

    this.callTargetCallback();
  },
  setTargetValueByOffset: function(offset, loose) {
    var value = this.getRatiosByOffsets(offset);
    var target = loose ? this.getLooseValue(value) : this.getProperValue(value);

    this.groupCopy(this.value.target, target);
    this.offset.target = this.getOffsetsByRatios(target);
  },
  getLooseValue: function(value) {
    var proper = this.getProperValue(value);
    return [
      proper[0] + ((value[0] - proper[0]) / 4),
      proper[1] + ((value[1] - proper[1]) / 4)
    ];
  },
  getProperValue: function(value) {
    var proper = this.groupClone(value);

    proper[0] = Math.max(proper[0], 0);
    proper[1] = Math.max(proper[1], 0);
    proper[0] = Math.min(proper[0], 1);
    proper[1] = Math.min(proper[1], 1);

    if ((!this.dragging && !this.tapping) || this.options.snap) {
      if (this.options.steps > 1) {
        proper = this.getClosestSteps(proper);
      }
    }
    return proper;
  },
  getRatiosByOffsets: function(group) {
    return [
      this.getRatioByOffset(group[0], this.bounds.availWidth, this.bounds.left),
      this.getRatioByOffset(group[1], this.bounds.availHeight, this.bounds.top)
    ];
  },
  getRatioByOffset: function(offset, range, padding) {
    return range ? (offset - padding) / range : 0;
  },
  getOffsetsByRatios: function(group) {
    return [
      this.getOffsetByRatio(group[0], this.bounds.availWidth, this.bounds.left),
      this.getOffsetByRatio(group[1], this.bounds.availHeight, this.bounds.top)
    ];
  },
  getOffsetByRatio: function(ratio, range, padding) {
    return Math.round(ratio * range) + padding;
  },
  getStepNumber: function(value) {
    // Translate a [0-1] value into a number from 1 to N steps (set using the
    // "steps" option)
    return this.getClosestStep(value) * (this.options.steps - 1) + 1;
  },
  getClosestSteps: function(group) {
    return [
      this.getClosestStep(group[0]),
      this.getClosestStep(group[1])
    ];
  },
  getClosestStep: function(value) {
    var k = 0;
    var min = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.options.steps - 1; i++) {
      if (Math.abs(this.stepRatios[i] - value) < min) {
        min = Math.abs(this.stepRatios[i] - value);
        k = i;
      }
    }
    return this.stepRatios[k];
  },
  groupCompare: function(a, b) {
    return a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1];
  },
  groupCopy: function(a, b) {
    a[0] = b[0];
    a[1] = b[1];
  },
  groupClone: function(a) {
    return [a[0], a[1]];
  },
  draggingOnDisabledAxis: function() {
    return (!this.options.horizontal && Cursor.xDiff > Cursor.yDiff) ||
           (!this.options.vertical && Cursor.yDiff > Cursor.xDiff);
  }
};


var bind = function(fn, context) {
  /**
   * CoffeeScript-like function to bind the scope of a method to an instance,
   * the context of that method, regardless from where it is called
   */
  return function() {
    return fn.apply(context, arguments);
  };
};

// Cross-browser vanilla JS event handling

var addEventListener = function(element, type, callback) {
  if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
  } else if (element.attachEvent) {
    element.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
  }
};

var removeEventListener = function(element, type, callback) {
  if (element.removeEventListener) {
    element.removeEventListener(type, callback, false);
  } else if (element.detachEvent) {
    element.detachEvent('on' + type, callback);
  }
};

var preventEventDefaults = function(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = window.event;
  }
  if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  e.returnValue = false;
};

var stopEventPropagation = function(e) {
  if (!e) {
    e = window.event;
  }
  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
  e.cancelBubble = true;
};


var Cursor = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  xDiff: 0,
  yDiff: 0,
  refresh: function(e) {
    if (!e) {
      e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.type == 'mousemove') {
      this.set(e);
    } else if (e.touches) {
      this.set(e.touches[0]);
    }
  },
  set: function(e) {
    var lastX = this.x,
        lastY = this.y;
    if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
      this.x = e.clientX;
      this.y = e.clientY;
    } else if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
      this.x = e.pageX - document.body.scrollLeft - document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      this.y = e.pageY - document.body.scrollTop - document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    this.xDiff = Math.abs(this.x - lastX);
    this.yDiff = Math.abs(this.y - lastY);
  }
};


var Position = {
  get: function(obj) {
    var rect = {left: 0, top: 0};
    if (obj.getBoundingClientRect !== undefined) {
      rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
    return [rect.left, rect.top];
  }
};


var StylePrefix = {
  transform: getPrefixedStylePropName('transform'),
  perspective: getPrefixedStylePropName('perspective'),
  backfaceVisibility: getPrefixedStylePropName('backfaceVisibility')
}

function getPrefixedStylePropName(propName) {
  var domPrefixes = 'Webkit Moz ms O'.split(' '),
      elStyle = document.documentElement.style;
  if (elStyle[propName] !== undefined) return propName; // Is supported unprefixed
  propName = propName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + propName.substr(1);
  for (var i = 0; i < domPrefixes.length; i++) {
    if (elStyle[domPrefixes[i] + propName] !== undefined) {
      return domPrefixes[i] + propName; // Is supported with prefix
    }
  }
};

function triggerWebkitHardwareAcceleration(element) {
  if (StylePrefix.backfaceVisibility && StylePrefix.perspective) {
    element.style[StylePrefix.perspective] = '1000px';
    element.style[StylePrefix.backfaceVisibility] = 'hidden';
  }
};


var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame;
var cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame;

for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
  requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
  cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] ||
                         window[vendors[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
};

if (!requestAnimationFrame) {
  requestAnimationFrame = function (callback) {
    return setTimeout(callback, 25);
  };
  cancelAnimationFrame = clearTimeout;
};

return Dragdealer;

}));

/**
 * Custom JS
 */ 

var draggie = new Dragdealer('image-carousel', {
  steps: 4,
  speed: 0.1,
  loose: true,
  requestAnimationFrame: true,
  vertical: true,
  horizontal:false,
  callback: function(x, y) {
    var active = parseInt(y*3);
    console.log(y, active);
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('li:eq('+active+')').addClass('active');
  }
});

$(document).on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  var eq = $(this).index();
  draggie.setStep(0, eq+1);   
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  background: #222;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 680px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 85px;
}
/* Image carousel */

#image-carousel {
  height: 350px;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: move;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
#image-carousel:active {
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
  #image-carousel .handle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400%;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
    #image-carousel .handle .slide {
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
    }

#image-carousel .pagination {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#image-carousel .pagination li {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#image-carousel .pagination li.active {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="image-carousel" class="dragdealer">
    <div class="handle">
      <div class="slide img1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/680x350/e74c3c/ffffff&text=Dragdealer" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide img2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/680x350/3498db/ffffff&text=Is" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide img3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/680x350/2ecc71/ffffff&text=Totally" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide img4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/680x350/7f8c8d/ffffff&text=Awesome" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="active"></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>      
    </ul> 
  </div>
  
   <div id="image-carousel" class="dragdealer">
    <div class="handle">
      <div class="slide img1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/680x350/e74c3c/ffffff&text=Dragdealer" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide img2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/680x350/3498db/ffffff&text=Is" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide img3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/680x350/2ecc71/ffffff&text=Totally" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide img4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/680x350/7f8c8d/ffffff&text=Awesome" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="active"></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>      
    </ul> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that allows you to replace your 'image-carousel' id. Each drag dealer instance needs a unique id for the Javascript to hook into.

For example:

```
function dragDealerInstance(elementId) {
    ...
}
```

Then you can create a new instance for each Drag dealer:

```
$(function() {
  var instanceOne = new dragDealerInstance('image-carousel-one');
  var instanceTwo = new dragDealerInstance('image-carousel-two');
});
```

You'll probably also want to update your CSS styles so that each instance has a global class (eg .image-carousel) that pulls in the styles, as it's bad practice to have more than one id on a single page.